# Genesis 25:22 - Who was הַנָּבִ֜יא The Prophet רִבְקָ֥ה Rivqah went to?

Tags: commentaries, navi-prophets, genesis-bereishith

**Genesis 25:22 - Who was הַנָּבִ֜יא The Prophet רִבְקָ֥ה Rivqah went to?**

- Commentary by Chizkuni on Bereishit 25:22 quoting וַתֵּ֖לֶךְ לִדְרֹ֥שׁ אֶת־יְהוָֽה could allude to one of many Nevi'im. -- Do we know any of their names or his name?

> 'ותלך לדרוש את ה, “she went to obtain an answer to her problem from one of the prophets in her time.” (Rash’bam) The answer she sought was why the fetuses inside her were engaged in a fight. She was well aware that her term of pregnancy had not yet been completed. She was afraid that after all these pains she might miscarry.

[https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.22?with=Chizkuni&lang=bi&aliyot=0]

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to find it, but have a vague recollection that __someone__ says it was _Avraham_. I may be mistaken, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the medrash says that she went to the school of Shem and Ever, and the other mefarshim discuss the attributes of one called a navi/prophet, the Bal Haturim [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.22?lang=bi&with=Kitzur%20Baal%20Haturim&lang2=en) the word לדרוש as:

> בגימטריא מן שם בן נח

that based on gematria, she went to speak with Shem, son of Noach.

Comment: Shem the son of Noach would have been 538 years old - and Shem did live to be 600 years old [ Bereishit 11:10-11 ] - **but was Shem a navi'?**

Comment: Check out the Ha'amek Davar and his explanation of how the word "navi" might be bing used here https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.22?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=bi